# Remmina can't ssh to machine by hostname

Tags: networking, ssh, ip, hosts, remmina

I am using ubuntu 18 with remmina to manage my ssh sessions.

I can connect to my machine (on local network) 
using:

- remmina with ip
- regular ssh with ip
- regular ssh with hostname

When trying to use remmina with hostname I get "can't find host" error.

What can be the problem?
Thanks

Comment: You could try to ping this hostname (with and without `.local` suffix). If ping succeeds, then reminna will too.

Comment: the thing is that the ping and ssh works while remmina won't